# Difference between ListAdapter.getView and ListView.getChildAt

Tags: java, android

My app's UI has a ListView to show the timeline of tweets and setup an `OnItemLongClickListener` to show another view with several buttons ("Reply", "Retweet", "Favorite", etc.).  inside my Adapter's `getView()` method.

**What I want**: In my test project, I want to test this feature by performing a long click on the first item in the timeline and then performing a click on one of the buttons.

The part of code looks like below:

```
timelineList.getChildAt(0).performLongClick();
favoriteBtn = (ToggleButton)timelineList.getAdapter().getView(0, null, timelineList).findViewById(cse.ust.twittermap.R.id.favorite);
favoriteBtn.performClick();
favoriteBtn.performClick();
timelineList.getChildAt(0).performLongClick();
```

This works but when I try to change the second line into:

```
timelineList.getChildAt(0).findViewById(cse.ust.twittermap.R.id.favorite);
```

The test project throws a NullPointer exception, because `findViewById()` return *null*.

**My Question:** What is the difference between `ListAdapter#getView()` and `ListView#getChildAt()`?

It seems both of them can return a reference to an item view in the list, but clearly there should be some differences between them. I also want to figure out why the `getChildAt()` method in the second line fails in finding views by Ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getChildAt` is not a method special to a `ListView`. It is implemented for each `ViewGroup` (View that can have children).

When your `ListView` is created, it has no children. Calling its adapter's `getView` method doesn't change that fact, it doesn't add any children.

Only when your Activity's content gets measured and laid-out, the `ListView` will start creating child views by calling its adapter's `getView` method repeatedly and adding the returned `Views` to its own list of children. Only after that, `ListView.getChildAt(x)` could return some non-null value.

The `ListAdapter.getView` method returns brand new `Views` (or just returns the recycled `View`) on behalf of ListView/GridView/etc. Your code should never call `ListAdapter.getView` itself (unless you do a Unit test).

`ListView.getChildAt` returns an already created `View` (created earlier by `ListAdapter.getView` on behalf of the `ListView`) Note that your `ListAdpater` may define many many list items (the value returned by `getCount`), but the `ListView` hosting the adapter will never have more children than can be visible at any given time on the screen. I.e. your `ListAdapter` may deal with 1000 list-items, but your `ListView` will never have more than 6 child `Views` (depending on size of screen and listview-item, of course).

Comment: how can I get the view of the the selected item in the ListView?

Comment: "listView.getSelectedView();" or when you have an adapter's position (position in the list of data in the adapter): "listView.getChildAt(position - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());"